# How to number and label equations displayed as a system

Tags: equations, numbering, align, amsmath

I have system of equations (2 consecutive lines of equations) that I need to display. I use to do this just using two consecutive `equation` environments, but then I noticed the spacing is rather larger between the equations. I've read up on the `align` environment, which works, but does it ensure the spacing between the equations won't overlap? I would like to be consistent with my approach and if I'm going to run into issues with `align` later, I assume learn a better option now.

The [`amsmath`](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) does cover most of the options (I believe `aligned` is another environment? But no multiple numbers/labels?) but it doesn't say how to include numbering and labels for each equation (for the ones where the option is available).

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide an MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use successive `equation`s to number a system of equations. Rather use `align` which naturally numbers each in the same, consistent way. To avoid selective numbering, use `\nonumber` (or `\notag`), and to provide unique tags to select equations, use `\tag{<tag>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{align}
           f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ax^2 + bx + c &= g(x) \\
           f(x) &= g(x) \nonumber \\
  dx^2 + ex + f &= f + ex + dx^2 \tag{quadratic}
\end{align}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The starred version `align*` removes all automatic numbering (like placing `\nonumber` next to each equation).

`align` does make sure the successive equations don't overlap, and also that the equations align horizontally with the placed `&` alignment marks.

`aligned` is similar, but is typically used to create an alignment with a single number. Here is the same example with `aligned`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
             f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    ax^2 + bx + c &= g(x) \\
             f(x) &= g(x) \\
    dx^2 + ex + f &= f + ex + dx^2
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```